# Do I need to worry about EMI/RFI/etc. for 110V and 12/5V electronics in the same electric panel?

Tags: arduino, switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage, emi-filtering

I am building an electric panel (steel) which will house automation equipment in my home. The box is 20x20x10 inches and will include the following (all attached via DIN rail):

- 12v and 5v switched power supplies
- GFCI breaker
- Arduino
- 8 channel Arduino relay

The following sensors which will be connected to the panel via XLR ports and then Arduino via terminal DIN blocks:

- Thermocouples (x3)
- Solenoids (x2)
- Motorized ball valves (x2)
- Pressure transducers (x2)
- 110v outlets driven by relay board and arduino digital pins (2-4x)

Overall...

1. Is EMI/RFI/other noise something I need to be concerned about in this setup where 110v and lower voltage (12/5/3.3v) equipment is connected?
2. If so, how can I best partition the panel box from HV (110v) vs. LV (<12v)?
3. Will plastic cable raceways suffice or do I need metal raceways (maybe this is overkill)?

Comment: Instead of worrying about EMI and RFI, I think **safety** is a more important issue when mains voltage is present. Be sure to **ground** your steel panel properly. An Arduino board doesn't emit so much EM waves that EMI or RFI is an issue, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use STEEL construction, for the magnetic shielding that material can provide.

Especially with thermocouples --- 40 microVolts per degree C --- you don't want spikes from motors, or microwave ovens, or light switches, or even the
interference from 10 ampere 60Hz power cabvles.

How bad can this be? We compute thusly

Assume 10 amps at 60 Hertz.

The dI/dT = 10amps * 377 radians/second
= 3,770 amps per second.

Assume a distance between the power wiring and the thermocouple wiring of 4" (10 centimeters). Assume the vulnerable cross_section of the thermocouple wiring is 4" region by 1mm wire_to_wire spacing.

We use the merged version of Biot_Savart and Faraday Law of Induction, for couipling between a rectangular circuit vulnerable to magnetic field, and a long straight wire "transmitter" positioned to be co_planar with our rectangular "receiver".

- V_induce = [ MU0 * MUr * Area / (2 * PI * Distance)] * dI/dT

where Area is the receiver rectangular loop (rectangle, for easy computation)

and Distance is between the Wire and the Loop (we ignore complex geometries here, because we want an order_of_magnitude of V_induce)

Using MU0 = 4 * PI * 1e-7 Henry/meter, and MUr = 1 (copper, aluminum, FR-4,air)
we simplify to

- V_induce = [ 2e-7 Henry/meter * Area/Distance ] * dI/dT

Remember this is for a CLEAN SINUSOIDAL POWER LINE WAVEFORM, no spikes from motor commutators, no rectifier surges from microwave ovens.

- V_induce = 2e-7 * (10cm/1mm)/10cm * 3,770   answer in volts
- V_induce = 2e-7 * 1mm * 3,700 = 2e-7 * 3.77 = 0.8 microVolts

With NO SPIKES, 4" separation form power cables and thermocouples.

=================================================

Howeer, rectifier spikes in your power supplies can easily be

- 1 amp average (100 watt power supply), 10 amps peak (easily) in 10 microSeconds if little EMI suppression inside that (cheap) power supply

Thus the dI/dT of power supplies is easily

- 10 amps rising in 10 microseconds, or 1 Million amps per second

Notice the 1Million, compared to the pure sinusoidal 3,770 (10 amps clean power) is 250X larger coiupling, or 250 microVolts.

Thus the thermocouple interferer went from 0.8 microVolts to 250 microVolts.

And this ignores electric field coupling.

**** people will argue, rightly so, that twisted pairs in power cabling (HOT twisted with RETURN) reduces the aggressor fields. And people will argue that twisted pairs of the Thermocouple wires will reduce vulnerability to the aggressor fields. I agree. But sloppy, irregular, slow_rate_of_twisting will not provide these benefits.

===========================================

Power supplies will be switch_mode, for "efficiency", but that becomes useless when you need massive EMI/RFI filtering to have successful sensors/wiring near these supplies.

Within the supplies will be 200 volt/100 nanosecond nodes (drains of power MOSFETs) that must be heatsinked (perhaps 5% loss, via heat, plus a baseline charge switching heat_loss), and these 200volt/100nanosecond nodes will couple to the OUTSIDE thru any little gaps in the cases of these power supplies.

Thus electric fields will be a problem.

Expect to need a partition between the high_voltage region and the sensor wiring.

====================================

Also read and understand the BobFlux answer.

Comment: Just checked- enclosure is actually steel. Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can best protect internal components to the enclosure? I have read about partitioning the HV part of the enclosure but not sure if actually needed OR if I can simply place HV at bottom of enclosure and LV at top

Comment: @analogsystemsrf- Super helpful! Thanks so much for breaking this down for me. So to summarize: 1) keep 4 inches of space between high voltage power supplies and low voltage wiring, 2) twist wires inbound/outbound to sensors and other peripherals (e.g. twist +/- pair to motorized ball valve from arduino, twist +/-/data lines from arduino out to thermocouples, etc.)

Correct?

Comment: Excellent explanations- Thanks so much for taking the time to share this information. Will let you know if I have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the layout, it's apparent the Arduino Uno is not EMI-hardened. No ground plane, no ESD filters on the inputs, very few ground pins on the connectors...

[image]

Likewise, the little modules that go with it (pictured here is a thermocouple module) present the same problems. Notably, flimsy ground connection via a pin.

[image]

If you have high current loads like solenoids, valves, mains outlets switched by relays, etc... or simply if lightning strikes in the vicinity of your house... you can expect AC electromagnetic fields, which will induce common mode voltages into the cables you will plug into this panel.

This will create common mode currents flowing in your cable shields, and into the cables themselves if they are not shielded. If cables form a loop, then AC current will be induced.

The end result will be current trying to flow into your circuit's ground, which is quite high impedance considering the above. This can result in noise voltage spikes between different points on the PCB called "ground" which will result in noisy ADC readings, crashing micro, or even blow the chip if it's bad enough.

Likewise, if say the ground on both sides of your arduino (top and bottom connectors in the picture) is not at the same potential due to AC current drawn by the microcontroller, then the cables plugged on both sides will act as dipole antennas and radiate this noise into the world.

A counter example is this PC case:

[image]

Notice all the connectors on the back panel have their shields in contact with the back panel itself, which shorts all their grounds together with a flat metal plate, which has  very low inductance.

If, say, you're electrically charged and zap the USB mouse with an ESD spark from your finger, a high current spike will go through the mouse. Since it's ESD-hardened, ESD current will be shorted through caps and ESD protection components inside the mouse so everything stays at more or less the same potential. Then a current spike will flow from the electrically charged mouse through the cable (shield and wires). Most of it will go through the shield, then into the back panel, then straight to Safety Earth. Some of it will go through the wires, then hit the ESD protection components on the PC motherboard, which will short it to chassis ground which is also connected directly there. Thus this current spike will not go all the way through the PCB ground itself, it will not induce noise voltage into it, and the PC will not crash, which is what you want.

Considering how cheap double sided PCBs have got, I'd do the following:

One double sided PCB, with one side an uninterrupted ground plane. This will be your "chassis ground".

Pins to mount the arduino in the middle.

Pins for all your little modules and interfaces where you need them.

Terminals for wires you want to connect to your arduino.

1nF SMD caps to ground plane on all the slow digital signals going in and out, maybe a resistor in series with the output signal.

That should be much more resilient. Also more convenient, since you can route the arduino pins to terminal blocks on the PCB, label them with silkscreen, etc.

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thanks for sharing. I have this item- will this have the same result to prevent EMI/EDS? https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B087PBMCZW/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s04?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: This looks nice. No ESD components but it solves the arduino ground problem.